# How create a Zig-zag layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place some controls in a zig-zag pattern as shown below. How do I best accomplish this?

(Using Android 2.2)

[image: Zig-zag :)]

Comment: What are the constraints? The easiest would be to place two vertical LinearLayouts next to each other and add some padding on the second one. However, IF you want the children to line up in a special way you're probably going to have to do something custom...

Comment: So how would you make sure the padding is half of the children's height?

Comment: that depends on how you define the height of the child

Comment: then you'll have to setup an OnGlobalLayoutListener, grab the measured height of the child, set the padding on the LinearLayout and then requestLayout().   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)